# Can I make an Action on QGIS to open a file(.tiff) on an attribute table directly to Photoshop

Tags: qgis, actions

Here is the sample file image to be opened.
Is there's a way to open an image file (.tiff) on the attribute table using an image viewer like Photoshop. Can I create an Action on QGIS so that it directly open on Photoshop application.

QGIS version 3.10
Windows 10

[image: sample file image]

Comment: Yes. I need to view an image file (.tiff) from the attribute table. Is there's a way to link the qigs to an image viewr which is photoshop.

Comment: You need to specify the application exe in the action  like "C:\Adobe\photoshop.exe" [%ImageField%]

Answer (score 1):

In **QGIS 3.12** created an action that has the image reference to a folder in the attribute.

Then setting up the actions to trigger Adobe Photoshop.

[image]

Note the application may use a default application (windows needs to be told to use photoshop)

/c is just to tell CMD to terminate after it completes

Image credit Wikipedia
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koala